# How to calculate the number of day-off trading like weekend, holidays?

Tags: datetime, pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading

Good Morning All!

The question in Pinescript,
Is there any trick to let my code determines whether the day before (yesterday) was day-off trading?

For example, I want my code to calculate the number of days-off.

I've coded this one, but it doesn't work perfectly at running data especially on the first day after off-market, but it works fine at historical data.

```
T=security(syminfo.tickerid, "1440", time)
fun()=>
    NumDays= change(T)/86400000
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
//@version=4
study("StackOverflow", overlay=true, max_labels_count=500)

daysBetween = change(dayofmonth(time))

if daysBetween > 1
    label.new(bar_index, high, tostring(daysBetween) + " days", yloc=yloc.abovebar)
```

Edit: New code example.
This should work better.
I've actually asked a question about this myself recently.
See [Detecting session breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64892091/detecting-session-breaks)

```
//@version=4
study("NewSession", overlay=true)

var int     days_off        = na
var float   change_in_ms    = na
var int     ms_per_day      = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

change_in_ms    := change(time("D"))

if change_in_ms
    days_off    := int(change_in_ms / ms_per_day)-1

bgcolor(change_in_ms ? color.yellow : na, 60)
plotchar(days_off, "days_off", "")
```

Comment: I appreciate your help!. Actually, I tried your suggestion before.
Here's an issue with using either dayofmonth(time) or dayofweek(time)
At between the end of that month (or week) and starting a new month (or week), the trick has a hole to not perform as required output.

Comment: I've added a new code example. Does this work better? If not, please explain what you're expecting by means of an annotated screenshot.

Comment: That's smart! Thank you so much Bjorn