# Detecting session breaks

Tags: pine-script

A question about session breaks.

I know that you can add Session Breaks to a chart by activating Session Breaks on the time scale of the chart.
It then appears as a vertical line on the chart, whenever a Session Break occurs, indicating the start of a new session.
That Session Break line can be formatted in the chart settings, under Appearance > Session Breaks.

[image: Session Break on chart]

I'm trying to detect that Session Break in Pine Script.
Is there a **reliable** way in Pine Script to detect the start of a new session?
Especially for futures contracts.

Typically, there's an amount of time (a pause) that passes between the stop of a session and the start of a new session.
Therefore, my idea was to check the time difference between the current bar and the previous bar.
If that time difference is greater than the "time width" of one bar, that means that there's been a "pause".
Hence, a new session has started.
That approach seems to work for most of the days.

However, when I look at futures ticker `NYMEX:NG1!`, that logic does not always seem to be correct.
Some days on that ticker seem to have "pauses" mid-session.
I suspect that trading was halted on those "pause" moments.
An example can be seen by comparing `27 Oct 2020` (normal day) to `28 Oct 2020` (irregular day with mid-session pauses).
For the example, I've put the chart in *Exchange timezone* on a *15 minute interval*.
The green background is my code detecting session breaks.

[image: Session Breaks]

On `27 Oct 2020` (normal day)
You can see that each bar starts 15 minutes later than the previous bar, which is normal and expected.
The session starts at `18:00` and progresses per 15 minutes:

```
18:00 - 18:15 - 18:30 - 18:45 - 19:00 - 19:15 - 19:30 - 19:45 - 20:00 - 20:15 - etc...
```

On `28 Oct 2020` (irregular day with mid-session pauses)
You can see that NOT each bar starts `15` minutes later than the previous bar.
The session also starts at `18:00` and progresses per 15 minutes, but NOT consistenly:

```
18:00 - 18:15 - 18:30 - (gap) - 19:15 - (gap) - 20:45 - (gap) 21:00 - 21:15 - 21:30 - 21:45 - (gap) - 22:30 - (gap) - 23:00 - (gap) - 23:45 - 00:00 - (gap) - 00:45 - (gap) - 03:00 - (gap) - 03:30 - (gap) - 03:45 - 04:00 - 04:15 - (gap) - 05:15 - 05:30 - (gap) - 06:00 - 06:15 - 06:30 - 06:45 - 07:00 - 07:15 - etc... (normal from here on).
```

My code for detecting session breaks (green backgrounds in the screenshot above)

```
//@version=4
study("NewSession", overlay=true)

var bool    newSession      = na
var int     bar_width_in_ms = timeframe.multiplier * 60 * 1000

newSession := change(time) > bar_width_in_ms

bgcolor(newSession ? color.green : na, 70)
```

In conclusion, my question is this:
Is there any ***reliable*** way in Pine Script to detect the start of a new session?
Especially for futures contracts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `change(time("1D"))` to track where one daily bar ends and another begins:

```
//@version=4
study("NewSession", overlay=true)
newSession = change(time("1D"))
bgcolor(newSession ? color.green : na, 70)
```

Comment: Simple and elegant solution :)

Answer (score 1):

'time_tradingday' - returns the start time(in ms) of the present session. This can be used as below.

```
//@version=4
study("New Session Detection", overlay=true)
var d = 0
T = time_tradingday
if(T!=d)
    d:=T
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=high, text="New Day")
```